# Problems with rotations in OpenGL

Tags: c#, opengl, rotation, quaternions, opentk

I'm developing a 3D application in OpenGL and I want to rotate the objects with the mouse like in AutoCad, SolidEdge or another CAD program. By the way, I'm totally new in 3D programing and OpenGl.
I've tried with GL.Rotate but as far as I know its complicated and not very attratctive for the user because one rotation around one axis affect the others. So I've been searching and I found the quaternions.  I thought I understood how they work but when I run the app the GLControl that Im using is totally white. Also In the debugging mode I've seen that the Matrix "Mat" is full with NaN and I think that that's the problem. The AngX and AngY are the angles of rotation that I change in the mousemove
This is what I've done:

The main loop:

```
Mat = Matrix4d.Identity; //Global
Vector3d vect1 = new Vector3d(0, -1, 0);
Vector3d vect2 = new Vector3d(-1, 0, 0);
QuatRot1 = new Quaterniond(vect1, AngX);//Global
QuatRot2 = new Quaterniond(vect2, AngY);//Global
QuatRot1.Normalize();
QuatRot2.Normalize();
Quaterniond.Multiply(QuatAcc, QuatRot1);
Quaterniond.Multiply(QuatAcc, QuatRot2);
Matrix4d.CreateFromQuaternion(ref QuatAcc, out Mat);// I think the problem is here
AngX = 0;
AngY = 0;
GL.MultMatrix(ref Mat);
```

The mousemove:

```
if (WheelPress)
{   //mouse1 previous mouse position
    //mouse0 current mouse position 
    AngY = 0.1f * (mouse1.X - mouse0.X);
    AngX = 0.1f * (mouse1.Y - mouse0.Y);
    Cursor.Current = Cursors.Hand;
    glControl1.Refresh();
}
```

PS.I don't know if it's important but im working with OpenTK